# Is tensor product of weighted Sobolev spaces dense?

Tags: real-analysis, sobolev-spaces, tensor-products

Let $W^{k}_{2,w_1}(\mathbb{R})$ be a weighted sobolev space with positive continuous weight function $w_1$ for the integrals of the function and its derivatives. Let $W^{k}_{2,w_{1,1}}(\mathbb{R}^2)$ be a weighted sobolev space with positive continuous weight function $w_{1,1}(x,y):=w_1(x)w_1(y)$. Is then  $W^{k}_{2,w_1}(\mathbb{R})\otimes W^{k}_{2,w_1}(\mathbb{R}) $ dense in $W^{k}_{2,w_{1,1}}(\mathbb{R}^2)$  under these conditions on the weights $w_1$ and $w_{1,1}$?

In particular, is $C_0^{\infty}(\mathbb{R^2})$ dense in $W^{k}_{2,w_{1,1}}(\mathbb{R}^2)$?

Comment: come on guys, not even a guess?

Comment: Next time I should pick an easy one....

Comment: is it hard enough to post it to terry tao?